# binding a listbox with List<string> inside a ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a problem with a binding on an List inside an ObservableCollection.

this is my XAML :

```
        <ListBox Background="Black" x:Name="Test" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding tags}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

This is my ObservableCollection.

```
    public ObservableCollection<ArticleJSON> Items { get; private set; }
```

This is my class ArticleJSON :

```
public class ArticleJSON
{

    public string content { get; set; }
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
}
```

My list tags isn't empty. If i bind on "content" it's work perfectly...
I hope someone can help me

Comment: If you bind "content" of the ArticleJson to the textBlock, is it displaying?

Comment: Have you tried with a OnPropertyChanged inside your Items declaration?

Comment: @iJayIf i bind "content" it is display. That's why i don't know why it doesn't work with my List<string>

Comment: What u want to show in textblock text ? Joined tags with any separator ?

Comment: you are binding a list to a `TextBlock` I'm not sure what you are expecting to happen but its just going to call`ToString()` on the list and display `System.Collections.List` which I doubt is what you meant...

Comment: @Puko, yes  , i want to display all my tags inside my listbox with separtor. I try to do that on a textblock for after make the textblock more beautiful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <Grid>
        <ListBox Background="Black" 
                 x:Name="Test" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox Foreground="Red" ItemsSource="{Binding tags}" >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red" Height="40"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: with this solution if my list is "a,b,c" i will have only one textblock with "a,b,c" is it possible to have one word in one textblock ? like textblock = a , textblock2 = b  ?

Comment: yes, u need replace your TextBlock in DataTemplate for next List which ItemsSource = tags and ItemTemplate `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>`

Comment: i tried this solution, but when i did that, my listbox is empty

Comment: Oh i didn't see. I tried with your update and ItemSource=tags and text="{binding} .
The listbox is still empty , i don't know why

Comment: @Fly_federer your items not showing becouse binding is fired soon as your collection is initalized .. U need to call propertychanged ... just for test remove binding and set itemssource from code behind

Comment: Thanks for all your answer, i never used it , so it's time for me to start with this property !. :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly bind `List<string>` to a Text block. Convert your List to a single string and bind it. to do that you can try a value converter.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=tags,Converter={StaticResource ListToStringConverter}}"/>
```

code behind,

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(List<string>), typeof(string))]
public class ListToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(string))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a String");
        // strings are joining with a comma, you can use what you prefer 
        return String.Join(", ", ((List<string>)value).ToArray());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```